# Code Signing Certificate doesn't work

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Hi All.
I bought Code Signing Certificate and sign my MSI installer, but when I download installer from my  site and run it Windows SmartScreen shows "Unknown publisher" warning.

Here is manual for signing from GoDaddy: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/signtool-sign-windows-code-with-a-code-signing-certificate-4778

Also I have tried DigiCert tools for signing but I had the same result.
Here is screenshot from my signed application:
[Application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpIoo.png)

Could anyone to help me?

Best regards,
Denis.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/du` parameter or maybe `/d` parameter. You can find documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx)

So the final command (base taken from [here](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/signtool-sign-windows-code-with-a-code-signing-certificate-4778)) would look like

```
SignTool sign /f path to your PFX file /p your PFX file password /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /td SHA256 /du "http://company.url" /d "My company" path to the code you want to sign
```

Comment: I have tried but without result. 
Here is command for signing:
`C:\Users\deav>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /a /f "C:\Users\user\Desktop\certificate.pfx" /p password /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /td SHA256 /du "https://example.com" /d "Company" /debug "C:\Users\user\Downloads\application.msi"`

Comment: After Private Key filter, 1 certs were left.
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: Company
    Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    Expires:   Thu Dec 20 03:03:01 2018
The following additional certificates will be attached:
    Issued to: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
    
    Issued to: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: C:\Users\user\Downloads\application.msi

Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0